# Genymotion - Unable to start the Virtual Device / Cannot create COM object

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

I'm sorry to bring this up again, I know there's about 20 more questions about this, read through all of them and all the answers and I still can't get this to work

### What I tried so far is,

Using an older version of VirtualBox (4.2), with this version, old android versions (4.1 and 4.3) worked fine, but nothing over 4.3 (5.0 and 6.0 which are the ones that I need), it said failed to import OVA everytime I tried with anything over 4.3. Also tried deleting cache and re-downloading

Adding DCHP server on the network adapter, it was already there

When using VBox 5.0 (latest), none of the android version work, they download fine but then give the "Unable to start the virtual device" error, and if I try starting it up via VirtualBox it says "Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object" and then "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine -vmachine name- "

Enabling amd virtualization on BIOS, it was already enabled

Reinstalling different versions of VBox and reinstalling genymotion

### Computer specs

AMD FX-8350

M5A97 R2.0 Asus motherboard

8GB RAM

R9 290x PCIE

Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

-

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running as an administrator? Do you have the necessary permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple more hours of research and trying odd ways to fix the problem, I tried a solution that some people used when they couldn't start VirtualBox at all, and it somehow fixed the problem, so if anyone else needs it, here's what I did:

1) Uninstall VirtualBox

2) Delete the following key directories on the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

3) Install latest version of VirtualBox (5.0)

Then I simply headed into genymotion and downloaded Nexus 10 with android 5.1.0 and it worked! Hope it helps someone